# How to define Has Many Through in EFCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Given the following entities:

```cs
public class User
{
    public int Id;
    public List<Team> Teams { get; set; } // how to setup this in EFCore?
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id;
    public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
}

// Pivot
public class Member
{
    public int Id;
    public string Role;

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

How can I define in EFCore configuration that the `User` has many `Team` through the `Member`?

I know I can just create a property that derived from the `Member` but wondering if it can be define in EFCore instead.

```cs
public class User
{
    public int Id;
    public List<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public List<Team> Teams => Members.Select(m => m.Team).ToList();
}
```

Something similar to Laravel (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all turn your fields into properties:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Then if you do not want to change the navigation properties you can setup it with fluent API in `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(u => u.Teams)
        .WithMany()
        .UsingEntity<Member>();
}
```

Also check out the docs for [EF Core: Many-to-many relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many), there are different options to setup this structure including fully qualified relationships which will not require explicit fluent API config (but may require some logic when writing queries).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class User{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<Member> Memberships {get; set; }
}

public class Team{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<Member> Members {get;set; }
}

public class Member{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Role { get; set;}
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public User User { get; set; }
   public int TeamId { get; set; }
   public Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

1. The `User` class now has a collection of `Member` called `Memberships`.
2. The `Team` class has a collection of `Member` called `Members`.
3. The `Member` class includes foreign key properties `UserId` and
   `TeamId` to represent the relationships with `User` and `Team`
   respectively.
4. The navigation properties (`User`, `Team`) are included to establish
   the   relationships.

Comment: Please refer [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and make your answers more readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Entity Framework Core, you can define a many-to-many relationship with a join entity using the Fluent API. In your case, you have a many-to-many relationship between the **User** and **Team** entities through the **Member** entity.

To configure this relationship, you can use the following code snippet in your **DbContext** class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(u => u.Members)
        .WithOne(m => m.User)
        .HasForeignKey(m => m.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
        .HasMany(t => t.Members)
        .WithOne(m => m.Team)
        .HasForeignKey(m => m.TeamId);
}
```

This will create a join table named **UserTeamMembers** with two foreign key columns: **UserId** and **TeamId**.

If you want to access the **Teams** property of the **User** entity without manually defining the property, you can use the Include method when querying the data to eagerly load the related entities:

```
var users = _context.Users
    .Include(u => u.Members)
    .ThenInclude(m => m.Team)
    .ToList();

foreach (var user in users)
{
    foreach (var team in user.Members.Select(m => m.Team))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"User {user.Id} is in team {team.Id}");
    }
}
```

This will retrieve the User entities along with their related **Member** and **Team** entities in a single query.